# Watermark under the picture (9gag.com style)

Tags: php, gd, watermark

I want to make watermark like on this site: http://9gag.com

The main thing of it is to put a strip **under** the image instead of placing it in the picture. I want to make it using PHP with GD libaries. Any help would be appreciated best one will be an example code or ready to use one :)

Greetings!

Answer (score 8):

Create an image that is x pixels taller, copy the original image into it at position `(0,0)` and then the watermark at position `(0,original_height)`:

```
$image = 'foo.jpg';
$watermark = 'watermark.png';
$imagesize = getimagesize($image);
$watermarksize = getimagesize($watermark);
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($imagesize[0], $imagesize[1] + $watermarksize[1]);
imagecopy($img, imagecreatefromjpeg($image), 0, 0, 0, 0, $imagesize[0], $imagesize[1]);
imagecopy($img, imagecreatefrompng($watermark), 0, $imagesize[1], 0, 0, $watermarksize[0], $watermarksize[1]);
imagejpeg($img);
```

Not tested, but it should work like that. The code assumes that the watermark is not wider than the original image.

Comment: Doesn't handle variable image widths.

Comment: Well after I checked it I can say, it work with variable image widths until the watermark width is smaller than image, that's fine! @ThiefMaster can you plz tell me how to change background color of this stripe and how to make watermark at right bottom corner? (now it is at left bottom corner). And first of all BIG THANK YOU!!

Comment: `imagecolorallocate()` to create a color, `imagefilledrectangle()` to draw a box (use the same size as in the second `imagecopy()` call and put the code before calling that function). You could also simply `imagefill()` the whole image before copying anything.

Comment: Can you put those functions in the code you provided? just the watermark at right and any color i will change it later. (btw. the change of position of the watermark to the right will not spoil the whole stripe expansion?).

Answer (score 1):

Not as easy if you want it to look good.

The bottom stripe requires 3 chunks, that is left, middle and right for the bottom stripe. It is recommended that all 3 chunks have the same height.

[image: Here you go]

Use

```
imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($original_picture), imagesy($original_picture)+$stripe_height);
```

Then:

- Left side is `imagecopymerge(...)`
- Right side is `imagecopymerge(...)` but you need to calculate the x destination by subtracting the width of the right chunk from the width of the input image
- Between left and right (again, do the math, its easy) use `imagecopyresize(...)` to add the middle chunk. Use that function to make sure it's scaled linearly between the left and right chunks.

Comment: Grigore are you a cartoonist? simple drawing but it have something :D and btw. I see you know what youre talking about, maybe you can prepare some more ready to use code for me?

Comment: Haha, it's just the default chisel from Snipping Tool, I have an IBM X61T. Also, no time to write the whole thing, but it's easy to do. If you can't do it though, just go to Elance and pay an Indian $15 to do it for you.